# How to fix java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in java

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am creating one java application that consists of usb library that was downloaded from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javausbapiforwi/) but it was showing an error called **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lucasAndresForni_Win32 in java.library.path** please helpme to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that library is in your PATH and is the same bit-ness as the JVM.

As it appears that it is looking for a 32-bit DLL, this will only work on a 32-bit JVM on Windows.

Comment: where i can download the 32bit DLL @Peter Lawrey

Comment: @RDDivisionMedequip You need to ask the provider of the library (or the JAR)  This is not a library I recognise.